# AWS 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, http-status-code-503

My front-end connecting to my server which host in AWS, and from yesterday I getting 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable error.

In chrome console I have 2 errors :

1 :

```
http://myServerendpoint.com/getData 503 (Service Temporarily Unavailable)
```

2 :

```
Failed to load http://myServerendpoint.com/getData : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://myFrontEndPoint.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.
```

I already apply cors  to the server ( it's nodejs ) :

```
app.use(cors({
   allowedOrigin: ["*"],
   credentials: true
}))
```

and it was working until yesterday. but from yesterday I keep getting this error and have no clue. in aws logs I getting this :

```
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused “exec: \“/usr/bin/node\“: stat /usr/bin/node: no such file or directory”
```

Any idea what is wrong?

UPDATE :

The path was wrong I change it to correct one which is /usr/bin/node but now I getting permission denied error :

```
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"/usr/bin/node\": permission denied"
```

my docker file :

```
FROM node:6-onbuild

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y install sudo

RUN mkdir -p /usr/bin/node
RUN chmod -R +x /usr/bin/node
RUN sudo chown -R $USER: /usr/bin/node
WORKDIR /usr/bin/node

COPY package.json /usr/bin/node
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/bin/node

ENV PORT 80
EXPOSE ${PORT}

CMD [ "npm","run", "start" ]
```

NEW Update :

Even after build with buildkite, the duckerfile config run fine :

```
Removing intermediate container eac44b8f2a3f
Step 3/12 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/bin/node
 ---> Running in 9ac2ac7f960e
 ---> 970134252f9d
Removing intermediate container 9ac2ac7f960e
Step 4/12 : RUN chmod -R +x /usr/bin/node
 ---> Running in 8c54b0e3d813
 ---> 5ca0fe8180f6
Removing intermediate container 8c54b0e3d813
...
...
...
Successfully built 7f189f7e38cc
Successfully tagged 239820024964.dkr.ecr.ap......
```

So the problem is not before building, its after build, when we send a http request we got this permission denied!

Comment: The message "/usr/bin/node: no such file or directory."  seems to be the issue. Is there a node executable there?

Comment: @RodrigoM You was right, the path was wrong, now I add the correct path which was /usr/bin/node but this time I get container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"/usr/bin/node\": permission denied"

Comment: Do you start the node? is there a sh script? looks it does not have permissions(chmod) to excute.

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran Actually this run with docker and I already used RUN chmod -R +x /usr/bin/node but still getting the permission error

Comment: Could you please post your dockerfile?

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran I add the docker file in question

Comment: I tried to build a sample app with this dockerfile and it works fine.

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran Yea in my local I also can build using ducker and its fine, the problem is in production, not sure what will go wrong but when I check cloudwatch logs, I still get permission denied. I use buildkite

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran I update the question, as u can see even in buildkite, the dockerfile build successfully, the problem is after build not before. when I send a http request I get permission denied

Comment: what you see in "docker logs"? Do you see your container when you do "docker ps"? I guess, when you get this error, the container will not be started, you can see failed containers with "docker ps -a"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We find the problem, in case if someone needed, in my case, our ecs task EntryPoint had a different path for the node, basickly our docker node path located on : /usr/local/bin/node BUT our ecs task entrypoint was set to /usr/bin/node